# Normal PHP array for exclude section of WordPress query?

Tags: php, exclude, wp-user-query

I just wanted to check on something with the community here and avoid any future drama.

I have a variable which seems to be working fine in a `wp_user_query` but not sure if I'm missing something that will trip me later on.

I have the following in on a page template:

```
<?php

// WP_User_Query arguments
$args = array(
    'role'           => 'editor',
    'exclude'        => $userID,
    'number'         => '999999',
    'count_total'    => false,
);

// The User Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// The User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        // do something

         echo $user->display_name;

    }
} else {
    // no users found
}


?>
```

WordPress is expecting is an array in the exclude section like this:

> Array ( 1 , 2 , 3 , 4  )

However When I use

```
<?php print_r($userID) ?>
```

I get an array that looks like this

> Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )

Do I need to strip the key and replace it with a comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just seeing the indices (indexes).

```
<?php

$array = array( 1,2,3,4 );
print_r( $array);

/*
outputs: 
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @TMdesigned, good to have somewhere to double check these things.